# Yii + EasyPHP Runtime Path not Writable?

Tags: apache, permissions, yii, easyphp

I'm trying to get a Yii program running, but I get the error:

Application runtime path "C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\project\protected\runtime" is not valid. Please make sure it is a directory writable by the Web server process.

Does this mean I have to change something inside EasyPHP? I've tried adding permissions through directory->properties->security and changing the permissions to allow everything, but that did nothing. I have no idea where to go from here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That either means the directory doesn't exist or you need to CHMOD it with the right permissions. `chmod -R 777 runtime`

Since you're on windows, you shouldn't need to CHMOD anything. Are you absolutely sure that the runtime directory exists?

Otherwise I would suggest using [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). I'm running yii on it locally with no problems.

Comment: There wasn't a runtime (or an assets folder I found out)! I cannot thank you enough. I had pulled the project from a code repository, so I didn't even think to make them myself. Thanks again. I was working on that for hours.

Comment: No problem. Just remember not to accidentally commit those folders later ;)

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem with Yii. Yii creates a lot of empty folders. And I was using a GIT repository to work between the production environment and my DEV machine. GIT by default doesn't save empty folders. So when I was working on my DEV machine, I cloned the repo minus all the empties. Use this command on a Linux machine, from the root of your repo, to put empty ".gitignore" files in each of the empty directories. This will make sure git indexes and saves them.

`find . \( -type d -empty \) -and \( -not -regex ./\.git.* \) -exec touch {}/.gitignore \;`